# Image Size option does not appear in Insert Image of CKEditor

Tags: drupal-8

I installed Drupal 8.9.x but when I press the Image option on the CKEditor, I get a window that does not contain "Image size" (that defines the image width and height). I only get image selecting, Alternative text, Align and Caption options.
[the option without Image Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMPCB.png)
In tutorial videos in YouTube I see that the Image Size does appear:
[Option with Image Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ick6r.png)

Any idea why is that?
How do I get the Image Size option?
Can it be fixed? if yes, can someone assist how to add it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Media and Media Library core module
Edit text format (admin/config/content/formats) to include "media" to include "Insert from Media Library" icon to "Active toolbar" and enable filter "Embed media" with filter settings set to "Image" for "Media types selectable in the Media Library" and "Media library" for "View modes selectable in the 'Edit media' dialog".
Create new content using Article (default) and using new media icon upload and insert image to CKEditor.
Currently "Edit media" modal has fields for "Alternate text", "Align" and checkbox "Caption". Having fields for width and height here would be useful. see if this helps

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3132211

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I don't understand what do you mean by "Enable"? Do you mean "Install"? I can not insert a photo to my (this) question for some reason, but both modules you mentioned are not "Installed" and when I go "Extend", do "search with "image", I see that the checkbox of both Media and Media Library are not checked (and therefore not installed, I believe). should I press the "Install" and install them?  Thanks again for answering.

Comment: I installed the Enable Media and Media Library modules, and then I tried to find the admin/config/content/formats but I didn't find "content" nor "format" under "admin/config" option. Is it in some other menu? Thanks for answering.

Comment: I didn't find how to do it by following your answer. I tries all options of CKEditor configuration, but didn't find the options in your answer. Can you assist please? Thanks.

Comment: In the Admin menu toolbar there you will see a menu named Configuration when you hover on that a dropdown will appear there you will see content authoring when you hover on that then you will see test format rest you can follow from my previous answer ,i hope it helps.